# **.h: No such file or directory when compile C in dec c++

Tags: c, file

I encounter `[Error] interp1_pos2013b.h: No such file or directory` when I compile c programs in windows10 dev c++.

File Directory is as follows：

project1: `C:\Users\18843\Desktop\新建文件夹`

interp1_pos2013b.h：`C:\Users\18843\Desktop\新建文件夹\project1\inter1pos`

I have added `interp1_pos2013b` in folder `inter1pos` and add the folder under project1, As shown in the picture：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXLXV.png)

I don't know how to solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you include only a file name, it means, that the file is located near your source file.

In your project, the `interp1_pos2013b.h` is not in the same folder as `velocity_optimize.c`.

Write:

```
#include "inter1pos/interp1_pos2013b.h"
```

instead

```
#include "interp1_pos2013b.h"
```

With this, you tell the compiler the relative path of the header file.

Comment: Please always use a `/` as directory separator in `#include`. Using a backslash is technically UB.